# How to get variable out from the Splunk mvc.createService().get() function?

Tags: javascript, splunk, splunk-sdk

sorry for posting this, but I need some help and another pair of eyes. I must admit that everything that I have found here on stackoverflow, splunk docs and splunk community answers, and of course tried, it failed on me.

What I want to achieve is to read from a custom config file (file details below) and get that result out to be used in other part of the code for a double check.

Conf file details:
name `config.conf`,
the stanza is named `download`,
the property is called `version` which may have value of `new` or `old`.

The code is:

```
define(["jquery", "react", "splunkjs/mvc", "splunkjs/splunk"], function ($, react, mvc, splunk_js_sdk) {
  
  const e = react.createElement;
  const useEffect = react.useEffect;

  // Get version from conf file
  var version;
  mvc.createService().get("/servicesNS/-/my_app/properties/config/download", {}, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error:" + err);
      return;
    } else {
      version = response.data.entry[0].content;
      console.log("Version from conf: " + version);
    }
    return version
  });
...........Rest of the code (React)..........
});
```

...which works and displays the version in the console.log `Version from conf: old` inside function, but my real issue (which I am not able to see it) is that I am not able to figure it how to get out that result into a variable, for example:

```
var version = old
```

This looks like an asynchronous function with a promise (not sure) but my knowledge (I must admit) is not so great in this area.

I have found my inspiration from [here](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Dashboards-Visualizations/Is-it-possible-to-access-properties-from-a-custom-config-file/m-p/223585) and I have adjusted a bit for my needs.

In the end I am thanking in advance to anyone who will shed a bit of light for me here.

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not the best idea, or solution, but I have exposed the variable into a hidden field value in my page and from there I was able to use it anywhere in my code pages.

Until another idea will pop up, I am satisfied with my solution.

Thanks to anybody that have had a look on this and to anybody who will contribute further on this.